# Cannot link MySQL with Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have MySQL hosted in Amazon RDS. I would like to Copy Data to my Azure SQL. I follow the instrunction here [Copy data from MySQL using Azure Data Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-mysql).

When I tried to add the source, it's success when I clicked Test Connection button. but when I try to submit it return this error

> Type mismatch: Expected to recieve a object.The relevant property is
>   'SecretBase'.The error occurred at the location
>   'body/properties/typeProperties/connectionString' in the request.

Tried to google this error but no luck. Below a screenshot :
[image]

Comment: This might be a bug in ADF v2, have you tried using google chrome developer and use the "Network" option to see how the GET and POST requests look like? this might give you a hint of what's going on and will help the MS support team as well, how does the JSON look like for this linked service?

Comment: Is your data factory hosted in West Center US? There's a bug in ADF and the fix will be released soon.

Comment: @saul I didnt check that yet, let me try that one.

Comment: @Bo yes, I'm using West Center US. probably that's the issue

Comment: have you upgraded your data factory to GA version? I think the fix was already released in GA version.